# toggle between two DIVs based on screen resolution using CSS

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

We are developing a new UI for one our products and for a number of reasons have the need to toggle between two `<div>` tags depending on whether the device be mobile or desktop.  Each `<div>` will contain appropriate content for either mobile or desktop, but because we only have a single HTML page, we need the ability to turn on one `<div>` while turning off the other one.

This question is something of a follow up to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213641/show-different-div-based-on-screen-resolution) which is very similar to what I am asking here.  To recap the solution found there, there are two `<div>`s:

```
<div class="visible-phone">
    content for phone
</div>

<div class="visible-desktop">
    content for desktop
</div>
```

and there are two CSS rules which employ either the maximum or minimum screen resolution:

```
.visible-phone{
    @media (max-width: 480px) { more css }
}

.visible-desktop{
    @media (min-width: 768px) { more css }
}
```

To get to the point, consider a device with a minimum width of 700px and a maximum width of 900px.  This would fall through the cracks of the above CSS logic and would result in neither `<div>` being visible.  As another example, a device ranging from 500px to 750px would also not be covered.

Can anyone suggest a full-proof approach to avoid the weakness in the referenced answer?  CSS based solutions would be preferred here.

Comment: Add a media query for the range in between and decide which content to show (or create additional content for tablets).

Comment: @Paul This is a clever idea, but let me play the devil's advocate.  Suppose we added (480, 768) as third media query.  But now a device which ranges from (450, 700) would again not be covered.  Whoever cooked up this media query stuff clearly enjoyed mental torment :-)

Comment: Why wouldn't that be covered? Depending on various factors, it will just show different `div`s, for example when rotation from portrait (450) to landscape (700) mode.

Comment: The potential problem here is that even if we define several tight ranges, if a device _overlaps_ a boundary condition, then it ends up falling into no category.  Remember, the criteria for falling into a media query range is that your min is _greater_ than the bottom of the range _and_ your max is _less_ than the top of the range.

Comment: Are you sure on that? To my knowledge, a media query of `max-width: 480px` applies to all viewports that are 480px or below.

Comment: But even if it is that way, you could have `max-width: 480px` (first media query) and `min-width: 479px` for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is display none within the media query.  Use the different classes assigned to each div such as mobile and desktop then in the media query for desktop set .visiblephone{display:none;} and query for mobile set .visible-desktop{display:none;}

This will ensure that within your specified media query one div will always be hidden, then you just have to get your screen size values =)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly you are trying to do:

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .visible-phone{
    display: block !important;
  }
  .visible-desktop{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .visible-phone{
    display: none !important;
  }
  .visible-desktop{
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am currently trying something along these lines, but I see a potential problem here.  Suppose a device has min width 400px and max width 800px.  The first style would not be met because the `max-width` of 800px is too large.  But the second style _also_ would not be met, because the `min-width` of 400px is too small.  So, there could conceivably be devices out there which would fall into a no man's land.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe there is a misunderstanding on your side. Any device/viewport at any given time can only have one width. This _single_ width value (opposed to a range) is determining the media query to use.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i am trying to imagine the trouble like this." i have a browser window, which i can change its width between 400px and 800px. First style is works between 400px to 480px range, and after 480px the second one will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Media Queries

```
/* If the screen size is 600px wide or less, hide the element */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.example {
    display: none;
  }
}
```